# Do I only have to mock out external dependencies in a unit test? What's about internal dependencies?

Tags: unit-testing, integration-testing

Do I only have to mock out external dependencies in a unit test?

What if my method that I want to test, has a dependency on another class within the same assembly? Do I have to mock out the dependency for going sure to test only one thing and there for to make a unit test instead of an integration test?

Is an integration test a test that tests dependencies in general or do I have to difference between internal and external dependencies?

An example would be a method that has 2000 lines of code with 5 method invocations (all methods coming from the same assembly).

Comment: Your first problem is that you have a method with 2000 LOC

Comment: Ofc. But this is made by some one else. Me and my team has to be the super stars transforming shit into gold ... or so :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally a proper unit test is testing *only* that single piece of code.  So a scenario like this is where you start to ask yourself about the coupling of these two classes.  Does Class A internally depend on the implementation of Class B?  Or does it just need to be supplied an instance of Type B (notice the difference between a class and a type)?

If the latter, then mock it because you're not testing Class B, just Class A.

If the former, then it sounds like creating the test has identified some coupling that can (perhaps even should) be re-factored.

**Edit:** (in response to your comment)  I guess a key thing to remember while doing this (and retro-fitting unit tests into a legacy system is really, really difficult) is to mentally separate the concepts of a class and a type.

The unit tests are not for Class A, they are for Type A.  Class A is an implementation of Type A which will either pass or fail the tests.  Class A may have an internal dependency on Type B and need it to be supplied, but Type A might not.  Type A is a contract of functionality, which is further expressed by its unit tests.

Does Type A specify in its contract that implementations will require an instance of Type B?  Or does Class A resolve an instance of it internally?  Does Type A *need* to specify this, or is it possible that different implementations of Type A won't need an instance of Type B?

If Type A requires an instance of Type B, then it should expose this externally and you'd supply the mock in your tests.  If Class A internally resolves an instance of Type B, then you'd likely want to be using an IoC container where you'd bootstrap it with the mock of Type B before running the tests.

Either way, Type B *should* be a mock and not an implementation.  It's just a matter of breaking that coupling, which may or may not be difficult in a legacy system.  (And, additionally, may or may not have a good ROI for the business.)

Comment: case 2 fits: Before I refactor, I (should!) have to create a unit test, because it is possible to create some new bugs. I am speaking of an bigger enterprice systems that is tightly coupled. I also asking myself how to do this?

Comment: David, there is no difference between a Type and a Class. A class is a Type. Probably what you mean is the difference between an object and a class...

Comment: @BrunoBrant: It's a semantic difference, but semantics are everything here. A "type" in a language sense is a class, but a "type" in a logical (language-agnostic) sense isn't necessarily the same thing. In C# for example an interface or an abstract class is more of a "type" by defining a contract of functionality. A class provides its own contract which claims to meet the criteria of the type's contract (as well as perhaps others, and perhaps even more of its own), and finally the object is the fulfillment of the contracts. In this case he's testing each contract, regardless of the class.

Answer (score 4):

**Working with a code base you're describing isn't easy** with **multiple problems combined** into something you don't know how to start changing. There are strong dependencies between classes as well as between problems and maybe even no overall design.

In my experience, this takes a lot of effort and time as well as skill in doing this kind of work. A **very good resource** to learn how to work with legacy code is **Michael Feather's book: [Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://www.informit.com/store/product.aspx?isbn=0131177052)**.

In short, there are safe refactorings you can do without risking to break things, which might help you get started. There are also other refactorings which require tests to protect how things work. **Tests are essential when refactoring code**. This doesn't of course come with a 100% guarantee that things don't break, because there might be so many hidden "features" and complexity you cannot be aware of when you start. Depending on the code base the amount of work you need to do varies greatly, but for large code bases there is usually a lot of work.

You'll need to **understand what the code does**, either by simply knowing it or by finding out what the current code does. In either case, you **start by writing "larger" tests** which are not really unit tests, they just protect the current code. They might cover larger parts, more like integration/functional tests. These are **your guards** when you start to refactor the code. When you have such tests in place and you feel comfortable what the code does, you can **start refactoring the parts the "larger" tests cover**. For the **smaller parts you change you write proper unit tests**. Iterating doing various refactorings will at some point make the initial large tests unnecessary because you now have a much better code base and unit tests (or you simply keep them as functional test).

Now, coming back to your question.

I understand what you mean with your question, but I'd still like to change it slightly because there are more important aspects than external and internal. I believe a better question is to ask **which dependencies do I need to break to get a better design and to write unit tests?**

The answer to this question is you should **break all dependencies you are not in control over, slow, non-deterministic or pulls in too much state** for a single unit test. These are for sure all external (filesystem, printer, network etc.). Also note that multi-threading is not suitable for unit tests because this is not deterministic. For internal dependencies I assume you mean classes with members or functions calling other functions. The answer to this is maybe. You need to decide if you are in control and if the design is good. Probably in your case you are not in control and the code is not good, so here you need to refactor things to get things under control and into a better design. Michael Feather's book is great here, but you need to find how to apply the things on your code base of couse.

One **very good technique for breaking dependencies is [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)**. In short, it changes the design so that you pass in the members a class uses instead of letting the class itself instantiate them. For these you have an interface (abstract base class) for these dependencies you pass in, so you can easily change what you pass in. For instance, using this you can have different member implementations for a class in production and when you do unit test. This is a great technique and also leads to good design if use wisely.

Good luck and take your time! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, a method with 2000 lines of code is just plain BAD. I usually start to look for reasons to make new classes -- not even methods, but classes -- when i have to use the pagedown key more than three or four times to browse through it (and collapsable regions doesn't count).

So, yes you do need to get rid of dependencies from outside and inside of the assembly, and you need to think of responsibility of the class. It sounds like this one has way too much weight on its shoulders, and it sounds like it is very close to impossible to write unittests for. If you think testability, you will automatically start to inject dependencies, and downsize your classes, and BAM!!!There you have it; nice and pretty code!! :-)

Regards, 
Morten

Comment: easy said =) when you have methods with thousands lines of code which have a lot of method invocations to methods that have also thousands lines of code :) The problem I have is that there is a rule that tolds me to refactor only when I have a unit test. But as you described creating a unit test for this bullshit code is nearly impossible (imo it is absolutely impossible). So without unit test you can break functionalities when you refactor and the chance to do that in such a code nightmare is in my opinion relative high. Welcome to the real world :(

Comment: Yeah, the real world really sucks sometimes. Sadly, I have to admit that I have also created monsters like the one you describe, but NEVER again!!! If test-first-then-remake is the  policy (which kind of makes sense), you should definitely stub and muck all that you can. Hopefully, you can reuse this megatest for integration purposes later on, when your refactoring is done, and you are the proud father of dozens of small new, pretty single-responsibility classes :-)